# Python cidr net address handling with standard lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipv4, cidr

Need is simple: from a single IPv4 address in cidr format (e.g.: "192.168.80.22/24") extract relevant info:

- address:   "192.168.80.22"
- network:   "192.168.80.0"
- netmask:   "255.255.255.0"
- broadcast: "192.168.80.255"

Is there an "easy way" to do this ("easy", in this context means "without actually coding a parser"), possibly using just the Python Standard Library (I *think* `ipaddress` can't do this, but I might have misread docs)

Reason why I *think* `ipaddress` can't handle this is I tried:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ip = ipaddress.ip_address("192.168.80.22/24")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ipaddress.py", line 53, in ip_address
ValueError: '192.168.80.22/24' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
>>> ip = ipaddress.ip_address("192.168.80.22")
>>> ip = ipaddress.ip_network("192.168.80.22/24")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ipaddress.py", line 74, in ip_network
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ipaddress.py", line 1504, in __init__
ValueError: 192.168.80.22/24 has host bits set
>>> ip = ipaddress.ip_network("192.168.80.0/24")
```

Apparently host addresses and net addresses do not mix

Comment: Yes, I think the `ipaddress` module can do this. What have you tried?

Comment: @Barmar: I updated O.P. , thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ipaddress.ip_interface`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html#host-interfaces) as follows:

```py
>>> import ipaddress
>>> 
>>> host4 = ipaddress.ip_interface("192.168.80.22/24")
>>>
>>> host4.ip                       
IPv4Address('192.168.80.22')       # address
>>> host4.network.network_address
IPv4Address('192.168.80.0')        # network
>>> host4.netmask 
IPv4Address('255.255.255.0')       # netmask
>>> host4.network.broadcast_address
IPv4Address('192.168.80.255')      # broadcast
```